# Hide (configurable) products with attribute

Tags: magento

I'm working on a Magento website, and what I would like to do is the following: I created an attribute to hide certain products. On a grid view page, I'm using the following code to exclude them from the list:

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('hideproduct')):?>
<?php else: ?>
```

Basically, it's just saying that when 'hideproduct' shows up, don't show anything.

This works for simple products, but for configurable products, it's a bit more complex, and it doens't seem to work with this. Let's say that I want to hide a product with a certain color, it always keeps appearing in the dropdown menu of the configurable product.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: What about product visibility and why are you using a custom attribute / hack?  You might be able to solve this another way.

Comment: Reason why I can't use visibility is that I'm using a custom extension where these products should be visible. The answer below solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i did for one of my task (if there is a better way please let me know)
You have to extend Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable for this purpose.
In it

```
public function getAllowProducts()
{
    if (!$this->hasAllowProducts()) {
        $products = array();
        $allProducts = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getUsedProducts(null, $this->getProduct());
        foreach ($allProducts as $product) {

            if ($product->isSaleable()) {
                if(!$product->getEcoReport())
                    {
                        $products[] = $product; 
                    }

            }
        }
        $this->setAllowProducts($products);
    }
    return $this->getData('allow_products');
}
```

eco_report is my attribute label.
So this is how it works... if for a simple product ( of a particular configurable product) if attribute eco_report is set then that product wont show in the configurable product's drop down list (on view page).
So all simple product's eco_report attribute has to be set so that it wont be shown on the configurable product's dropdown...